# Was ''millionth'' once spelled as ''millioneth''?

Tags: orthography

I've seen ''millioneth'' a few times in older books. Dictionaries seem to all say ''millionth''. Is ''millioneth'' simply incorrect or could it be that it is an old non-standard spelling.

Comment: The word _millionth_  is an ordinal number derived from a cardinal number ending in "n" just like ninth, tenth, eleventh, thirteenth and so on. According to [The Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/million) and other online sources the word "million" was adopted from French "million" (spelt the same but pronounced differently) around the 16th century and the French word was derived from the Italian "millione". It is possible that some people thought that "million" came from "millione" and, therefore, spelt it with an 'e' but no one does that now.

Comment: Prior to maybe 1850 there was no standard spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=millioneth%2Cmillionth&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmillioneth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmillionth%3B%2Cc0) then *millioneth* certainly looks much rarer than *millionth*, probably enough now to be described as incorrect

If you do a Google book search for the 17th and 18th centuries (not totally reliable), [*millioneth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22millioneth%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1600%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1800&tbm=bks) was less common than [*millionth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22millionth%22&lr=lang_en&biw=1704&bih=938&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1600%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1800&tbm=bks), though both seen relatively rare.  At that stage they might have been seen as variants, with *millionth* later dominating